# Allow moderators to add a user to a chat room by knowing their site IDs

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

Currently, if one wants to give a user special access to a room, one must know the users chat id. As a moderator, I can easily create a chat user for someone who doesn't have one (via superping), but I can't [find it easily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136504/link-to-chat-user-from-profile-page).

As mentioned in the update on the question I linked to, one needs to know the chat ID to provide access. This is rather cumbersome to do when you don't know the chat ID (but do know an SE profile)

I propose this:

In the "grant user access" area, allow the profile to be entered in `<site>.stackexchange.com/users/<userid>` form as well as the standard chat.se user ID.

[image]

If this will lead to rather heavy queries, at least let `<parent-site>.stackexchange.com/users/<userid>` work—in most cases you already know the parent user (when you use the superping), or can make a good guess (the user has only a few accounts)

Comment: Can't we change the whole user chatID in general? It never works properly in my experience, and the superping is clunky. Isn't there a better alternative to that that could be implemented instead? For instance include a global chat ID in the users profile and just use that everwhere (instead of superping, and also instead of having to specify both the site ID and the chat ID and all this confusing stuff). Add a new user to a chat by @[chat_userid] in the one single field.

Comment: @JonW: balpha says it's in the pipes (removal of the "parent user" crap/etc), but no update on that yet. [I already requested having the chat ids on the profile, it gained no traction :(](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136504/link-to-chat-user-from-profile-page)

Comment: There's this too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114296/streamline-moderators-contacting-users-through-chat

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez: I know of that one, _wants_ :)

Comment: Related (or possibly duplicate?): [Adding a new user to a chat room access list is confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119120). I think that dialog was designed in anticipation of each site having their own chat where the IDs would be in sync, the way it works now on chat.SE feels entirely broken.

Comment: @TimStone: Yeah, that's where parent user comes from as well.