# Granting write-access to room does not work as expected

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

I've created a public (not gallery, or private (mod-only)) room with the intent of talking to a user with low site reputation (less than 20). I know that a user needs 20 rep to chat but I noticed a button to "grant user explicit write access" which comes with the description "Explicit write access - 
Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room."

I go to grant the user write access...
[image]

...but when I click "change"...

...I get a nice red error message about needing 20 rep to talk.
[image]

So how is this function supposed to work? If they need 20 rep to talk the description should not read "reputation too low".

Comment: Only moderators can grant write access to users with less than 20 reputation. For regular users this is only useful in gallery chat rooms.

Comment: +1 Good point. @MadScientist Then he's right that the wording should change/be more precise.

Comment: @MadScientist, so I'd have to create a gallery room, then grant them access, then they have to request to join, then I accept...and then they can talk? :/

Comment: Somewhat related: [Adding a new user to a chat room access list is confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119120)

Comment: @tombull89 As a regular user you can't give someone write access to chat that doesn't have 20 reputation, only moderators can do that.

Comment: The description is correct though, as it's not describing what you can do by clicking the button, but the (currently empty) list of users in that group. If a user is in that list they can indeed chat even if their reputation is too low, you just can't *add* them to that list in that case without being a moderator. The clarification should probably be in the non-moderator "Please note..." message in the dialog.

Comment: @TimStone Exactly, the wording should be modified.

Comment: @JonClements What source could be more credible than Tim Stone?

Comment: I get why a moderator can do it, but I do not understand why the room creator/owner *can't* do it.